# How to style Validation checking before "save"

Tags: javascript, validation

This is just a best practice question that I have run into and can't find the answer for. Any input is welcome! (Backed up responses with data/research would be amazing)

**Example Save Button**

When my save button is pressed, I want to do some validation, name (must be first and last), age (must be from 0 - 125), email (valid email address) and if these are all true, I want to "save" the user (to a db or wherever doesn't matter)

Right now my functions are set up

```
// Global error handler for example
var errors = {};

// Save Button Function
saveButton = function(dataModel) {
  var valid = true;

  valid = validateName(valid, dataModel.name);
  valid = validateAge(valid, dataModel.age, 'extraParam');
  valid = validateEmail(valid, dataModel.email, 'secondParam', 'thirdParam');
  valid = (dataModel.red) ? validateRedUser(valid, dataModel) : valid;

  if (valid) {
    // Save user to database
  } 
  else {
    // alert to user an error has occured
    // user errors object to respond with the errors
  } 
}
```

**I feel like passing around the valid state to each sub validation function is not the best approach to a problem like this. It works, but can it be improved?**

Edit: A sub-validation function would look something like:

```
validateName = function(valid, dataModel.name) {
  if (!dataModel.name) {
    valid = false;
    // access global error handler to save error
    errors.name = 'error in the name';
  }
  return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your sample function added the valid state condition check.

```
validateName = function(valid, dataModel.name) {
  if (!dataModel.name && valid) {
    valid = false;
    // access global error handler to save error
    errors.name = 'error in the name';
  }
  return valid;
}
```

Comment: Not really what I was asking for. The code itself works as is. I'm looking for ways to improve the way the style of the code